# Stack gets corrupted and won't return

Tags: c++, stack, overloading

I have created my own stack and an overloaded function.  However when I call the function the return stack gets corrupted and I cannot figure out why :/ I am new to c++ and would love to learn! Here is my code

Main

```
int main(){
string line;
SStack s1(1000);
SStack s2(1000);
int cap = s1.getCapacity();
cout << "Is the stack empty? " << s1.IsEmpty() << "\n";
cout << "The capacity of the stack is: " << cap << "\n";
ifstream myfile("all.last.txt");
cout << "s1 begin pushing: \n";
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++){
    getline(myfile, line);
    cout << "Pushing " << line << "\n";
    s1.push(line);
}
cout << "s2 begin pushing: \n";
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
    getline(myfile, line);
    cout << "Pushing " << line << "\n";
    s2.push(line);
}
myfile.close();
cout << "Is the stack empty? " << s1.IsEmpty() << "\n";
string top = s1.top();
cout << "The top object on the stack is: " << top << "\n";
cout << "The size of the stack is: " << s1.size() << "\n";
cout << "Popping: " << s1.pop() << "\n";
cout << "Size after pop is: " << s1.size() << "\n";
s1 = s1 + s2;
cout << s1.top();
```

}

SStack function that doesnt return

```
    SStack::SStack(const SStack& s) : used(-1), Capacity(0), DynamicStack(0){
    *this = s;
}

SStack SStack::operator=(const SStack& s){
    if (this != &s){
        int cap = s.getCapacity();
        DynamicStack = new string[cap];
        Capacity = cap;
        used = -1;
        for (int count = 0; count < s.size(); count++){
            DynamicStack[count] = s.DynamicStack[count];
            used++;
        }
        }
        return *this;
}

SStack SStack::operator +(const SStack& s2){
int size1 = used + 1;
int size2 = s2.size();
SStack result = *this;
if (size1 + size2 <= Capacity){
    for (int count = 0; count < s2.size(); count++){
        result.push(s2.DynamicStack[count]);
    }
    return result;
}
else{
    cout << "Error stack is not big enough";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to the *minimum* program required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Use a debugger, set up breakpoints, observe your variables. Don't just dump heaps of code. Please see [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: ... and include all, that is needed, e.g. the class definition ("SStack.h") is missing.

Comment: I've used breakpoints and still cannot figure out the problem.  The stacks add correctly but when it goes to return it calls the destructor and deletes all the information

Comment: Which function doesn't return?

Comment: The operator + function

Comment: is your copy constructor / assignment operator / destructor OK?

Comment: I put them up. Sorry I am new at this

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning stack instances in 2 places, but I haven't seen an operator= definition.
I suggest you add an operator=() to your SStack class and delegate your copy constructor to this operator=(). Make sure your operator=() checks if it's copying itself:

```
...
SStack::SStack(const SStack &s) : used(-1), Capacity(0), DynamicStack(0)
{ 
    *this = s; 
}
SStack &SStack::operator=(const SStack &s)
{
    if (this != &s && s.size() > 0)
    {
        // check if we already have an allocated array
        if (Capacity < s.size())
        {
            // safe even if Capacity==0 as long as DynamicStack==0 too
            delete [] DynamicStack;  

            int cap = s.getCapacity();
            DynamicStack = new string[cap];
            Capacity = cap;
        }
        used = -1;
        for (int count = 0; count < s.size(); count++){
            DynamicStack[count] = s.DynamicStack[count];
            used++;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Try this with the degugger, and I suggest you recheck you "used" variable to make sure it actually has the index you want in all places it is used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: copy operations as in initializing?

Comment: I added an edit to clarify, you initialize your variables there, so that their values are not undefined when you enter your operator=() function. The copy operations are exactly what you do in your current copy constructor, with one more twist. The operator=() should check the current allocation, capacity, etc, and free everything so it can then allocate enough space to copy the entire external stack, if the current space is not enough.

Comment: Okay I will try that now

Comment: One more suggestion pertaining to readability: Usually, data members are either prefixed or suffixed with a \_ to identify them as such in the code. E.g. I would use either m_used, or \_used or used\_ for this data member.

Comment: Oh okay.  I seem to be getting a stack overflow error.  When the operator calls it keeps making new stack values. I updated the code above

Comment: Your code in the operator=() does not check if the SStack instance has already allocated an array of strings, and if the current capacity is enough to copy the external data. You need to add this check immediately after 

    if (this != &s) {  < here> ... }

so you can decide whether to free your existing array, and allocate another, or use it to copy the external data.  Also, can you show the call where it causes a stack overlow?

Comment: I am unsure how to check to see if the SStack instance has allocated an array.  The stack overflow occurs when I create the new string[].

Comment: One more quick edit. Check the value of s.getCapacity() before you use it. Sorry for the extended discussion-

Comment: Unfortunately it is still overflowing.  Whenever it returns it calls the operation over and over again

Comment: Show the point where you do a SStack x(y); or SStack x = y; and it causes a stack overflow please.

Comment: In the operation+ function I do a SStack result = *this; and it actually overflows at DynamicStack = new string[cap];

Comment: This indicates 'cap' is too large. Did you check it?

Comment: how could cap become that large?